# Установка yandex-maps: "NameError: name 'reload' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, yandex-maps-api, python-3.6, pip

Задача такова: поставить Яндекс карту в оконное приложение на питоне.
Уровень новичка с небольшими умением гуглить.
Прописываю в командной строке `pip install yandex-maps`, выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Полный текст:

```
Collecting yandex-maps
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/68/146b85edb855da98d1a56502328f762b4c3ed98fe53f590c55db3385f55f/yandex-maps-0.7.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\\yandex-maps\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\\yandex-maps\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\yandex-maps\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\yandex-maps\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\yandex-maps\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
    NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Версия 3.6.7, pip 19.3.1
работаю в pyCharm

Comment: В `setup.py` нет `reload`. Гугление сказало, что это раньше было встроенной функцией в `python 2`, но с `python3` уже нужно импортировать `from importlib import reload`. Т.е. если зайти в `"C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yh7q4kfw\yandex-maps\setup.py"` и добавить тот импорт, то **возможно**, успешно установится. Но есть сомнения, т.к. похоже этот модуль не поддерживает `python3`, а значит могут и другие проблемы возникнуть

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, умные люди сообщили, что это не поддерживается виндой в принципе.

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой